# error when deserializing a memorystream into a class if the "&" symbol appears in the xml text

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I get an error when deserializing a memorystream into a class if the "&" symbol appears in the xml text.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="DesEng")]
public class DesEng {
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="unit")]
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text{ get; set; }
}

var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
var temp = (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(ms); // error
```

The line on which the error appears.

```
<DesEng unit="per Sector">GSM/LTE Dual Mode license for Blade&AAU</DesEng>
```

Using  XmlWriterSettings { CheckCharacters = false } result did not bring. I'm getting an error "There is an error in the XML document (229, 70)". 
If I change the & symbol to another, then deserialization in the class passes correctly.

Comment: That's invalid XML as the ampersand is the start symbol for an HTML entity. If you want to have an ampersand in your XML it needs to be escaped as &amp;. The same applies for the < and > characters which need to be escaped as &lt; and &gt;. Whoever created the XML file needs to fix it.

Comment: It should be either &#nnnn; or &#xhhhh;  See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: You have something that isn't valid XML and you can't change it? That's a bit like having a program that won't compile and which you can't change. It's junk, fit only for the trash. Send it back to whoever supplied it and tell them it's useless.

Answer (score 1):

Try used the escaped form of the ampersand. You could replace it manually or you could replace it before you deserialise.

```
&amp;
```

For future reference, these characters also need to be escaped:

```
"   &quot;
'   &apos;
<   &lt;
>   &gt;
&   &amp;
```

See the answer posted in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1091953/2255454

Comment: I can not change the text of xml since it is accompanied by a checksum.

Comment: @ВладимирК That's something you should mention in your question; I suggest editing it in

Comment: You can't replace it in memory as I suggested? Depends when it is checked but you can open the xml file, use file to read it into memory and then use the replace function to replace it, then deserialise.

Comment: Это ошибка формата xml файлов допущена вендором huawei. Их java софт не ругается.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add "&" as a character in your xml. try used the escaped form of the ampersand.

Then your xml should be:

```
<DesEng unit="per Sector">GSM/LTE Dual Mode license for Blade&amp;AAU</DesEng>
```